# cross site scripting in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsp, xss

I am trying to resolve a cross site scripting exception in my code.
I'm getting an XSS error at line where I was using JSP expression inside a JS code

**ex:** 
**inside a JS function**

```
function ex(){
    .....
    var loc = '<%= location.getLocDetails()>';
    .....
}
```

Please let me know, if you have any solution/workaround?
Note: `location.getLocDetails()` returns a String

Comment: what does `location.getLocDetails()` returns? How does the source look like when the JS is run, and what is the url of your site? Are you really getting an error on that line, or on the line you're trying to use `loc`?

Comment: Do a View Source and update your question with the value that ultimately gets rendered in place of location.getLocDetails()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only means of XSS risks if `location.getLocDetails()` can return user-controlled input. If it for example returns the value *straight* from the HTTP `Accept-Language` header without any syntax checking or escaping, then there's indeed means of XSS risks.

You should **always** escape user-controlled input *during* display, at least every input which can to a certain degree be controlled by the client, including HTTP request headers and request URL's. It is basically is fairly simple, just use a display tool which escapes HTML entities `<`, `>`, `"` and `'`.

In case of JSP, easiest way is to use [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) (just drop [jstl-1.2.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) in `/WEB-INF/lib` if not done yet) [`<c:out>`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html) tag for this. Thus the particular line should be replaced by (assuming that `location` is already available in page, request, session or application scope):

```
var loc = '<c:out value="${location.locDetails}" />';
```

That said, it's right high time to get rid of all *scriptlets* in your JSP file, it would only make it better :) To learn more about JSTL, [read this](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html).

Comment: Another way to escape it is using ${fn:escapeXml(location.locDetails)}. I find it less cluttered.

Comment: @Manolo Santos: Matter of taste. If inside a HTML tag, e.g. `<input value="${fn:escapeXml(foo)}">`, then `fn:escapeXml` is nicer. If outside, it doesn't matter to me. The `c:out` has however as being a tag the advantage that you can put multiple expressions in it.